# How to use firestore local emulator in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

I would like to try firestore local emulator but resources are a bit scattered and it is hard to determine if it is possible in Node.js.
Has anyone already done that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some nice search, it is pretty easy in fact.

Here is a link to a [sample projet](https://github.com/Gnucki/firestore-emulator-hello-world) I made on github which makes a basic insertion followed by a retrieval.

It uses a docker container to run firestore emulator and `@firebase/testing` package to interact with it. The setup is straightforward and explained in the `README.md`.

Comment: Shouldn't need docker anymore w/ firestore emulator built in from firebase, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you an answer on this. It's quite a long time I didn't look at the last updates on the subject. If you have a newer solution, feel free to add it here !